How can I fix a loose TV mount screw on clay hollow brick?
The wall is made of the larger clay hollow brick (the red ones that we have in Europe), there is masonry/cement/mortar (not sure which) for connecting and putty + paint over them.
So my TV mount (one of those colloquially known as a VESA mount) became loose on one end (4 screws, just 1 loose for now), so I need to fix it.
First I assume (I have not loosened the screws) there are plugs (like the fischer duopower) that are inside the holes and then a screw screws into them. First, can I reuse the plugs that are already there if I unscrew all the screws to fix the loose one, or will I need to put new ones? Second, do I need some kind of masonry epoxy/filler or I can just put a new plug and screw in?
I know this might depend on the issue, but please give me a few ways that the situation can turn into, so I know what awaits me before unscrewing all the other screws and starting the job.
I do have a hammer drill if needs be and a few bits, so if redrilling is needed, let me know what needs to be done precisely.
Thanks.

FYI, VESA is a dimensional standard (an organization, really), not a device type.

@isherwood The name VESA mount is actually used to refer to a specific type of device in some parts of the world (just like hoover and dremel are in others).

Yeah, I know. I get lectured all the time about my mention of the misuse of terms. I'm not really interested in that. I'm interested in clarity of communication, which the term did not convey to all readers.

What not to do:

When putting an anchor for a heavy load into hollow brick you really want the plug to grab into at least one inner wall. The plug in the picture is too short.

can I reuse the plugs

No, and if they're duopower, pulling them out will probably be difficult.

do I need some kind of masonry epoxy/filler or I can just put a new plug and screw in?

It depends.
You need to check the hole: if it is not clean and round, or chips broke off from the brick, then a new plug won't work. In this case you either need to re-drill a larger hole and use a larger plug, or use a chemical anchor.
Then check the depth of the inner partition wall in the brick, see if you can get a long enough plug to grab it. If you can't, use a chemical anchor of sufficient length, which is the best solution anyway.

You need to use the sleeve, otherwise the mortar will fall off into the brick holes. It should be the correct length (like the one on the bottom).

Another solution is the poor man's chemical anchor: drill a much bigger hole, fill it with plaster or mortar, wait for it to set, then drill and use a normal plug like 8-10mm Fischer SX.

I do have a hammer drill

To drill into hollow brick, don't use the hammer, otherwise it will take off chips at the back leaving only a thin edge for the anchor to grab. Just set it to drill, use a masonry bit, and grind.
Here's a random pic from the internet showing the difference: when using hammer mode, the brick explodes leaving almost no material on the edges of the hole for the fastener to grab on. From the outside it may look okay but from the other side the hole actually looks like a crater. Without the hammer it's cleaner, it makes a hole with straight edges leaving a lot more material, so it's much stronger.


Thanks for the details!
How do I know how many inner walls are in the hollow brick and where I am exactly before tightening?
You mention that duopower is not easily removable, non re-usable, this video shows otherwise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IVzvubW7fk
Is he just risking it here?
Lastly, I've always thought that I need to use hammer drill mode on any bricks including the hollow ones in Europe! I do not however completely understand what you said here, it will take of chips off at the back of the brick? What do you mean exactly, also what do you mean by grinding?


Just remove the plug and poke inside the hole with a screwdriver to get an idea of the depth of the void an the next wall. Also you didn't mention the thickness of the brick, is it a partition wall like 5cm thick brick, or an outer wall like 20-30cm? 2) When you pull the plug out of the hole it it will be all scrunched up, not reusable. The plugs in the video are UX not duopower btw. 3) For the hammer I added a pic to the answer


If you drill a new hole, @appwizcpl, you'll know when A) you're through one partition wall, and B) When you hit a new one: the drill will lurch forward on you. At each lurch, you can stop and measure depth. If you can't fit a tape measure in the hole, simple insert a small wooden dowel until it stops, make a mark at the outside edge of the brick, and measure from the end to the mark. That's how far it is to the next partition wall. If it's not deep enough, drill through that partition and measure to the next one.

@FreeMan the thing is, the apartment already had the mount before I came in, so whoever did the job is not me.

You may need to drill new holes and move the mount a few inches (to avoid weakness from the old holes).

@bobflux I just fixed the issue, removed everything cleaned it and everything is good. Whoever put this before, was questionable, every hole was much bigger than the anchors, the anchors were basically half the length of the whole (so very shallow). Anyways, I replaced them all, hammered them in as it was tight (I could do it without) and screwed in. I just wondered about one thing, can I overtighten when using a drill? How do I know how much I can tight down the screw, I used a drill and as I increased the gear, it kept on screwing in. With a manual screwdriver of course, it did not bulge.

It's best not to over tighten, if you really abuse it the screw can act as a drill bit and drill the center of the anchor until there's no plastic left. Usually, it's by feel. But if it's tight with a manual screwdriver then it should be fine.
